# Hide data series from tooltip

Tags: echarts

How can I exclude a specific data series from showing in the tooltip with `tooltip.trigger = axis`?

I'm asking because I have a very complex graph with one line chart, two bar charts and one heatmap. And the heatmap has so many data that the tooltip ends up with too many lines. The heatmap values are not very important, so I would like to remove them from showing in the tooltip.

Right now I'm using `formatter` to exclude them, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I do exactly the same: adding a new attribute to the series and checking it from formatter.

Something like this:

```js
series: [{
// ...
  showInTooltip: true
// ...
}]

// ----

formatter: series => {
  var displayed = series.filter(item => item.showInTooltip);
  // work with displayed where showInTooltip === true
}
```

Also you can store callback instead attribute and it will work.

**Updated**: Suddenly I found undocumented feature and it will solved you trouble by the right way, apparently.

```js
series: [{
// ...
  tooltip: {
     show: false
  }
// ...
}]
```

Comment: Nice way of filtering the data, less logic to process.

Comment: Ah, the undocumented stuff. Thanks a lot, this is far easier to handle them. Less logic, less conflicts. I did try `tooltip: false` but didn't think of `show`.

Comment: @user8977154 I also tried with `tooltip: false` :-D. Using `show: false` works perfectly. @sergeyfedorov perhaps you could put that recommendation on the top of your answer? (for the lazy people that may get scared away by a workaround and forget to read untill the end...). ^^